# How to use VB.net Class in C# project?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I would like to use the below VB.Net class in my C# Project. Is there any way to do it?. 
Thanks in advance.

```
 Public Class XMLItemList
        Private sb As System.Text.StringBuilder

        Public Sub New()
            sb = New System.Text.StringBuilder
            sb.Append("<items>" & vbCrLf)
        End Sub

        Public Sub AddItem(ByVal Item As String)
            sb.AppendFormat("<item id={0}{1}{2}></item>{3}", Chr(34), Item, Chr(34), vbCrLf)
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            sb.Append("</items>" & vbCrLf)
            Return sb.ToString
        End Function     
    End Class
```

Comment: 1) It appears to be simple enough to translate 6 lines of VB into C#, if you don't need to keep it as VB, and 2) Why do people keep constructing XML using string concatenation, rather than, I don't know, actual components that understand XML.

Comment: Please, also, note how broken this class is. You can only call `ToString()` once, otherwise what it's returning definitely *isn't* XML.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create VB.NET `DLL` assembly (using Library project template from Visual Studio) and then you can add the reference of DLL assembly to your C# project. Be sure that the only public types (classes) are visible outside the assembly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Because both **VB.NET** and **C#** compile into **IL** (intermediate language), you can simply create a library (a DLL file) in VB.NET, and then use that library in C#.

Answer (score 3):

It's better to translate it into C#, and to fix the broken `ToString()` implementation:

```
  using System.Xml;

  public class XMLItemList
  {
    XmlElement el;
    XmlDocument doc;

    public XMLItemList()
    {
      doc = new XmlDocument();
      el = doc.CreateElement("items");
    }

    public void AddItem(string item)
    {
      var itemXml = doc.CreateElement("item");
      var attr = doc.CreateAttribute("id");
      attr.Value = item;
      itemXml.Attributes.Append(attr);

      el.AppendChild(itemXml);

    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
      return el.OuterXml;
    }
  }
```

Comment: It isn't necessarily the best idea.  Code duplication is never good.  This would be the best idea if they don't want to keep the original VB.Net version.

Comment: Well, my opinion is that the original VB version *isn't* worth keeping. The above, could of course, be translated back into VB.

Comment: Would like to +100 if I could..... that original code is indeed **beyond repair** - you can just hope it's biologically disposable bytes :-)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the class into C# or save the class in a class library and reference it in the C# project.